# Adding data to related table with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this to SQLAlchemy(using the Flask SqlAlchemy) objects defined:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30))
    email = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=True)
    friends = db.relationship('Friend', backref='user',
                                lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, username, password, email):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User('%s','%s','%s')>" % (self.username, self.email, self.id)


class Friend(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    friendId = db.Column(db.Integer)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, userId, friendId):
        self.userId = userId
        self.friendId = friendId
        self.created = datetime.datetime.now()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Friend(%i,%i)>" % (self.userId, self.friendId)
```

As I understand to add a friend I should be able to do something like this:

First getting the user:

```
MyUser = bpdata.User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
```

Getting the friend:

```
MyFriend = bpdata.User.query.filter_by(id=2).first()
```

Now I would like to do:

```
MyUser.Friends.Append(MyFriend)
```

Is this possible or do I just have to add the friend IDs directly into the table Friend?

Comment: I think you are creating wrong relationship. One user has many friends and same friend can be friend in many user so you have to use M2M instead of O2M.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured this one out my self..

What I needed to do was:

```
MyUser.friends.append(Friend(MyUser.id, MyFriend.id))
```

and then commit the update.

**Update:**

Ok I found the proper way of doing what I wanted. First I don't need the Friend table/class at all. Full code:

```
association_table = db.Table('association',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('friend_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30))
    email = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=True)
    friends = db.relationship("User",
                secondary=association_table,
                backref='added_by',
                primaryjoin=id == association_table.c.user_id,
                secondaryjoin=id == association_table.c.friend_id)
```

With this I can now do following:

```
>>> user1 = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
>>> user1.friends
[]
>>> user2 = User.query.filter_by(id=2).first()
>>> user1.friends.append(user2)
>>> user1.friends
[<User('user1','user1@admin.com','2')>]
>>> user1.friends[0].added_by
[<User('admin','admin@admin.com','1')>]
```